# Customize babel configuration in project created using create-react-app

Tags: babeljs, create-react-app

I want to use a babel plugin (babel-plugin-module-resolver) in a project created using create-react-app.

I know how to change babel configuration using npm run eject, but I would like to avoid it.

I was going to use react-app-rewired but I heard that there is the possibility to configure babel without ejecting and without additional libraries.

(if possible), how can I do it?